# What would a supersonic breeze feel like?

Tags: atmosphere

Most of us have been in a 60km/hr gale, if only for a brief gust. It roars, it knocks down trash cans, it can make us stumble, but it isn't all that *dangerous*.

The force of the wind can be estimated by *dynamic pressure*, which is $1/2 \rho v^2$ for air density $\rho$ and velocity $v$. Given that $\rho$ is about 1.3 kg/m^3 the dynamic pressure at 60 km/hr is about 180 Pa, or 18 kg/m^2. This is just enough to push a person off balance.

Suppose there is a planet with a very thin nitrogen-based atmosphere at Earth-like temperatures. So thin that a Mach 2.0 wind (680 m/s, 2450 km/hr) would push with about the same dynamic pressure as our low-grade gale on Earth. This would require a density of only 0.00078 kg/m^2, about *25 times less dense than mars*.

Such a planet somehow has supersonic storms from time to time. How would a low-density, high-speed wind feel like to an (anaerobic) person dressed in shirtsleeves? Could they reach out and touch the shock-waves? What would the wind sound like?

Are dust-storms lethal because sand and small debris picked up moves at the speed of a bullet? Would there even *be* sand or would it all get ground into extremely fine powder?

Comment: I count 6 different questions. We only take 1 per post.

Comment: Would you mind launching the person at 680m/s instead? The 2nd Law won't let you keep most of the kinetic energy of a gas relative to its environment (i.e. the ground, other air currents, dust) in its translational kinetic energy.